# devise goes crazy with accept headers of "*/*"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As an *authenticated* user, if I visit a url to my app via an external text editor, the mimetype shows up in the console as "*/*", and devise seems to redirect to "/sign_in" multiple times.  This is a problem because if I go to "/foo", this is initially stored in the session as the path to return to after authentication.  Due to the number of redirects, this value is blown away in the session and after devise finally realizes the user is already signed in, it ends up redirecting to "/".

For testing, I added to my application controller:

```
def authenticate_user!
  puts "***** AUTHENTICATE USER CALLED!!!"
  super
end
```

So, if I enter the url directly in my browser, the mimetype shows up as HTML, and it sees I am authenticated immediately and everything is rendered as expected:

```
Started GET "/products/171" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 17:04:53 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by LayoutsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"171"}
***** AUTHENTICATE USER CALLED!!!
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered html template within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1165ms (Views: 1127.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

However, when I click a link in an external text editor, I get this crazy behavior:

```
Started GET "/products/171" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 17:09:43 -0800
Processing by LayoutsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"171"}
***** AUTHENTICATE USER!!!
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms
I18N keys: [:en, :devise, :failure, :user, :unauthenticated]
I18N keys: [:en, :devise, :failure, :unauthenticated]
                 => You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.

Started GET "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 17:09:43 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
I18N keys: [:en, :sign_in, :submit_button]
                 => Sign in

I18N keys: [:en, :sign_in, :disabled]
                 => Your account has been disabled.

  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/sign_in (6.8ms)

Started GET "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 17:09:45 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
I18N keys: [:en, :devise, :failure, :already_authenticated]
                 => You are already signed in.

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 17:09:45 -0800
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by LayoutsController#show as HTML
***** AUTHENTICATE USER!!!

Completed 200 OK in 244ms (Views: 178.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Note the "Redirected to http://localhost:3000/" rather than http://localhost:3000/products/171, which is what should be happening.

Why does */* cause this behavior, and how can I fix this?

*UPDATE*

Apparently the problem is, I get a completely different sessions between visiting directly from the Chrome's url bar, and from clicking a link in an external text editor (even though the text editor is simply opening a new tab in chrome with that url):

from chrome after clicking link in external text editor:

```
request.cookies => {"_my_app_session"=>"f32dc5c239fadfc494a775990112f2b5"}
```

from putting url directly in chrome:

```
request.cookies => {"_my_app_session"=>"91ac136666b78499ea6e071f89cec7ee"}
```

How in the world is this possible?  It's the same browser..  I thought all tabs in a browser have the same session and there's no way you can change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what is happening here...  Microsoft Word is the "external editor" in question, and apparently it visits the url internally before kicking it off to your OS default browser.  I guess they are spying on their users to see where they are going and what the response of the site is before sending to a browser. That's why the session is different...